# Create object of System.diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#

I am creating a new Systems.Diagnostics object:

`System.Diagnostics.Process androidProcess= new System.Diagnostics.Process();`

But my code results in `InvalidOperationException` exceptions, and I don't understand why.

```
BasePriority = 'androidProcess.BasePriority' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
ExitCode = 'androidProcess.ExitCode' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
ExitTime = 'androidProcess.ExitTime' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

Why is my code generating these exceptions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code.  When are you getting these exceptions?

Comment: Cody is right.  Also avoid trying to run an Android program on Windows, wrong operating system.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you cannot access the values contained in those properties until the process has started. Before the process has started, it does not have a process ID or a handle associated with it.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.basepriority.aspx) for the properties confirms this, indicating that an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown under one of the following conditions:

> - The process has exited.
>     
>   -or-
> - The process has not started, so there is no process ID.

The solution is to *start* the process that you've created first, and then get those properties as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

BasePriority, ExitTime and ExitCode are read only. You cannot set these properties. They are set by the CLR or the started process itself.

Have a look at the MSDN:

- [BasePriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.basepriority%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
- [ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
- [ExitTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exittime%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)